# ClassRoll and Constructor methods

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

```
public class Exams {

private int score1 = 0;

private int score2 = 0;

private int score3 = 0;

 public void setScore1(int sc){
    score1 = sc;
}

public void setScore2(int sc){
    score2 = sc;
}

public void setScore3(int sc){
    score3 = sc;
}
public int getScore1(){
    return score1;
}

public int getScore2(){
    return score2;
}

public int getScore3(){
    return score3;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%-10s %-10s %4.2f\n", score1, score2, score3);

}
```

}

```
public class Student {

private String fName;

private String lName;

private Exams scores;

Student(String fn, String ln) {
    fName = fn;
    lName = ln;
    scores = new scores();

}

public void setScore1(int sc) {
    scores.setScore1(sc);

}

public void setScore2(int sc) {
     scores.setScore2(sc);

}

public void setScore3(int sc) {
     scores.setScore3(sc);

}


public String toSring(){
    return String.format("%-10s %-10s %4.2f\n", fName, lName, scores);
}

public double getAverage(){

}

public int compareTo(Student s){
    String name1 = lName + "  " + fName;
    String name2 = s.lName + "  " + s.fName;

    return ((lName + "  " + fName).compareTo(s.lName + "  " + s.fName));
}
```

}

```
public class ClassRoll {

private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
private String title;
private String filename = "data.txt";

ClassRoll(String f) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inpFileName = kb.next();
    File inpFile = new File(inpFileName);
    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

}

void Remove() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            students.remove(i);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void Display() {

}

void Add() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's second score?");
    int score2 = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's third score?");
    int score3 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Student already in class");
        } else {
            students.add(s);
        }
    }
}

void changeScore1() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore1(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void changeScore2() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore2(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void changeScore3() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore3(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

public void sortAverage() {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.getAverage() < s2.getAverage()) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void sortNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void save(){

}
```

}

I have a program with a couple of different classes. In the classroll class after I declare the private variables I have to create a classroll constructor "ClassRoll(String f)" that is suppose to .....

Read the class roll data from the input file f, creates Student objects for each of the students and adds them to the ArrayList of students. The input file contains the course title on the first line. The data for each student appears on a separate line consisting of first name, last name, score1, score 2, and score3 separated by at least one space.

I tried my best to start it off but I'm confused and don't really know the right way of making it. Can someone please help

Thank you

Comment: Show us how hard you have been trying. Let the sweat drip! Show your attempt (even if its not working).

Comment: Hey, what happens if your set score methods in student use the set score methods in exams to actually change the scores? Food for thought. Probably unrelated to your actual question.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh   ' Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inpFileName = kb.next();
        File inpFile = new File(inpFileName);
        Student s = new Student;'

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh i did what I could best think of before i got stuck

Comment: You wrote `sc = score1;` -- that should be `score1 = sc;` of course; same for score2 and score3.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt in what class? And does that help for the constructor in classroll

Comment: The setters are not doing anything in either class. And if you think that that code is not relevant to your question, then you should not have posted it here. Please read the Help section on how to ask a good question.

Comment: lol ok, I added an answer, see if it helps?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt well that class is used in the classroll class that I need help in. I edited it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have replaced the `SE` with the `scire1,2,3`

When you get a var in setter method it need to be placed in a property of your class.

Just replace with this code:

```
public void setScore1(int sc){
       score1=sc;
    }

    public void setScore2(int sc){
        score2=sc;
    }

    public void setScore3(int sc){
        score3=sc;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell why you down vote? As a stackoverflow  member you should know that you don't down vote without explanation.

Comment: I don't like to get downvote when my answer was correct please can you comment what is the problem( whoever down voted)

Comment: Downvoters are under absolutely no obligation whatsoever to explain their votes. Search [meta] and [meta.se] for *many* discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

> Read the class roll data from the input file f, creates Student
>   objects for each of the students and adds them to the ArrayList of
>   students.

Ok, so basically, we have to get student's information from some file and add it to some ArrayList. Alright, lets create an ArrayList for storing stuff first.

```
ArrayList<Student> studentInfo = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

You already have this code to read from file:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String inpFileName = kb.next();
File inpFile = new File(inpFileName);
```

Lets move on....

> The input file contains the course title on the first line.

So first element in `kb.nextLine()` is the course title. This means that we have to start adding student data from second line aka skip the first line. Alright....

> The data for each student appears on a separate line consisting of
>   first name, last name, score1, score 2, and score3 separated by at
>   least **one space**.

So basically, if we manage to split lines from `space` characters, we get data. Now to implement this:

Lets create a `boolean` variable to check if its first line or not:

```
boolean firstLine = true; // True - because it starts from first line
```

Time to start reading lines....

```
String courseName = ""; //I'll just store in a string, use as you wish

while(kb.hasNextLine()){
    if(firstLine){
        courseName = kb.nextLine(); //Set courseName if its first line
        firstLine = false; // We have moved past first line
    }
    else{ // Otherwise get student data
        // Lets store the student data in a string. This is just one line.
        // Something like: "FirstName LastName score1 score2 score3"
        String studentData = kb.nextLine();

        // Now time to split up data (so we get names/scores separately)
        String[] stData = studentData.split("\\s"); //Remember they have spaces between them. \\s --> A pattern that matches one or more spaces
        //So we can use those to separate data

        // This is how String[] stData contains the student information:
        // stData[0] = first name of student
        // stData[1] = last name of student
        // stData[2] = score1
        // stData[3] = score2
        // stData[4] = score3
        // Use this data however you like

        //Now that we have separated data, lets add the student object to ArrayList since we got all details.
        studentInfo.add(new Student(stData[0], stData[1]);
        // This last line of code is probably not going to do the trick.
        // You may need to make changes to your code to do stuff
    }
}
```

In any case, I have told you how to read the problem and how to proceed. You have all the strings, the firstname, lastname and scores. Now its upto you to figure out how to use them. Although the last line of code may not work for your, but its a hint to proceed.

Rest you should try figure out yourself first, since its no fun if I do all the homework ;)